# Copy array of objects and filter based on a property

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```js
Persons:[ 
{
Name: 'xz',
Job:'abc',
Manager:true},
{
Name: 'xy',
Job:'ac',
Manager:false},
{
Name: 'z',
Job:'a',
Manager:true}
]
```

I want to filter out the objects for which manager is true and set state i.e. `Person_new:[]` with this data using `setState`.

Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Is Person_New a new variable? or are you trying to replace the same state variable?

Comment: Person_new is An array?

Are you trying to find one person or multiple?

Comment: so `const managers = persons.filter( p => !!p.manager )`?

Comment: Person_new is a different state and contains array of objects in the same way as Persons. I want to override the content of Person_new with that of Persons for which manager is true

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a boolean key in your array of objects, you can use `filter` to pick out only the `Persons` with manager set to true like so!

```
const managers = Persons.filter(person => person.Manager)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Array filter method to identify the managers and then use the setState method:

```
const Persons = [
  { Name: 'xz', Job: 'abc', Manager: true },
  { Name: 'xy', Job: 'ac', Manager: false },
  { Name: 'z', Job: 'a', Manager: true }
];

const managers = Persons.filter(person => person.Manager);

this.setState({ persons: managers });
```

Comment: thanks @John Ruddell for correcting

Comment: yep! saw the extra whitespace there and figured I'd help :)

Comment: @Simon Thiel Person_new is a different state and contains array of objects in the same way as Persons. I want to override the content of Person_new with that of Persons for which manager is true

Comment: you mean like this? this.setState({Person_new: Persons})